# NetworkOnMainThreadException while launching coroutines via `Dispatchers.IO`

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, networkonmainthread

I'm attempting to make a basic network call using the View/ViewModel/UseCase/Repository pattern. The main async call is performed via Coroutines, which are both launched using `Dispatchers.IO`.

To start, here is the relevant code:

**ViewModel:**

```
class ContactHistoryViewModel @Inject constructor(private val useCase: GetContactHistory) : BaseViewModel() {
    // ...
    fun getContactHistory(userId: Long, contactId: Long) {
        useCase(GetContactHistory.Params(userId, contactId)) { it.either(::onFailure, ::onSuccess) }
    }
}
```

**GetContactHistory UseCase:**

```
class GetContactHistory @Inject constructor(private val repository: ContactRepository) : UseCase<ContactHistory, GetContactHistory.Params>() {

    override suspend fun run(params: Params) = repository.getContactHistory(params.userId, params.contactId)
    data class Params(val userId: Long, val contactId: Long)
}
```

**Base UseCase class used above:**

```
abstract class UseCase<out Type, in Params> where Type : Any {

    abstract suspend fun run(params: Params): Either<Failure, Type>

    operator fun invoke(params: Params, onResult: (Either<Failure, Type>) -> Unit = {}) {
        val job = GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) { run(params) }
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { onResult(job.await()) }
    }
}
```

**Finally, the Repository:**

```
class ContactDataRepository(...) : SyncableDataRepository<ContactDetailDomainModel>(cloudStore.get(), localStore),
        ContactRepository {

    override fun getContactHistory(userId: Long, contactId: Long): Either<Failure, ContactHistory> {
        return request(cloudStore.get().getContactHistory(userId, contactId), {it}, ContactHistory(null, null))
    }

    /**
     * Executes the request.
     * @param call the API call to execute.
     * @param transform a function to transform the response.
     * @param default the value returned by default.
     */
    private fun <T, R> request(call: Call<T>, transform: (T) -> R, default: T): Either<Failure, R> {
        return try {
            val response = call.execute()
            when (response.isSuccessful) {
                true -> Either.Right(transform((response.body() ?: default)))
                false -> Either.Left(Failure.GenericFailure())
            }
        } catch (exception: Throwable) {
            Either.Left(Failure.GenericFailure())
        }
    }
}
```

**Summary:**
Placing a debug breakpoint in that `catch{}` block in the repository (seen directly above) shows that a `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` is being thrown. This is strange, given that both coroutines are launched with a context of `Dispatchers.IO`, not `Dispatchers.Main` (Android's main UI thread).

**Question:**
Why is the aforementioned exception being thrown, and how can this code be corrected?

Comment: You'll need to provide the stack trace to even begin answering that question, since we cannot infer from the provided code what is actually calling the function and causing the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Marking a function `suspend` does not make it suspendable, you have to ensure the work actually happens in a background thread.

You have this

```
override suspend fun run(params: Params) = repository.getContactHistory(params.userId, params.contactId)
```

which calls this

```
override fun getContactHistory(userId: Long, contactId: Long): Either<Failure, ContactHistory> {
    return request(cloudStore.get().getContactHistory(userId, contactId), {it}, ContactHistory(null, null))
}
```

These are all synchronous, your `suspend` modifier is not doing anything here.

A quick fix would be to change your repository like this

```
override suspend fun getContactHistory(userId: Long, contactId: Long): Either<Failure, ContactHistory> {
return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    request(cloudStore.get().getContactHistory(userId, contactId), {it}, ContactHistory(null, null))
    }
}
```

But a much better solution would be to use the Coroutine adapter for Retrofit.

Comment: Even if the suspend function never suspends it is being called in a `CoroutineScope.async` context, so it should execute on the IO dispatcher regardless.

Comment: Marking a function suspend does make it suspendable. Problem here is it was being suspended in Main.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is is that you're not creating a coroutine anywhere. You can use the higher order function `suspendCoroutine` for this. A simple example would be like so:

```
private suspend fun <T, R> request(call: Call<T>, transform: (T) -> R, default: T): Either<Failure, R> {
        return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            continuation.resume(try {
                val response = call.execute()
                when (response.isSuccessful) {
                    true -> Either.Right(transform((response.body() ?: default)))
                    false -> Either.Left(Failure.GenericFailure())
                }
            } catch (exception: Throwable) {
                Either.Left(Failure.GenericFailure())
            })
        }
    }
```

There's a lot of ways you can go with this, too. Note this function will never throw an exception. I think that's intended, but if you want to propagate it upwards to be able to wrap it in a `try-catch` block for example, you could use `continuation.resumeWithException(...)`.

Since this function returns an actual coroutine, your `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` should work as intended. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using GlobalScope

https://elizarov.medium.com/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc

Launch the coroutine from the ViewModel with launch() and make all the repo functions `suspend`, and change context in the repo function with
`withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`